# What were the names of the 70 languages that Moshe spoke

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, language

Is says in the Torah Moshe gave one last speech to Klal Yisroel in 70 languages before he died, what were the names of the 70 languages, also did Moshe know how to write the writing script of the 70 languages

Comment: I don't think this is in the Torah. If anything it is a Midrash.

Comment: You are thinking of Devarim 27 8 with Rashi care of Sota 32a. There are other medrashim that reference seventy languages as well.

Comment: 70 could reasonably be construed as "a lot".

Comment: _Rashi_ to 1:5 also, @user6591.

Comment: Mordechai also knew seventy languages as did Joseph (and pharoah). It seems to have been common in those early times.

Comment: He wrote the Torah in 70 languages. I've never heard that he gave a speech in 70 languages. That would've been one long drosho.

Comment: @newcomer common? Because 2 people know it, and besides Joseph was taught by a malach

Comment: Well if pharaoh knew it and Moses grew up there he could also have learnt it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is not to be taken literally, even though there is a tradition of 70 nations and 70 languages. These seventy languages refers to '70 intentions' of torah as the [Ateres Hamikra](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_49122_5.pdf) quoting *Ha'kethav Ve'hakabbalah* explain (see Midrash Bamidbar  Rabbah 13:15). Or even *secrets* of torah since the expression סוד ה׳ ליראיו the word Sod equates to 70 (see Agadas Bereishis 15:1).

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept that there are seventy nations (other than Israel). see for example the 70 bakar on Sukkot - one for every nation - or the reading - tovim dodeikha miYaYiN  (YYN = 70, from shir ha shirim, see Targum).

So the idea 70 nations, 70 languages, that the speech was made to be understood and intended to be understood by all the peoples of the world, not just Israel. 70 languages, Mamash?   does it matter? This is aggadah.